# How to enable server side heartbeat for RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, stomp

I'm using web-stomp plugin + SockJS/Stomp.js on PhoneGap and observed that under circumstances (probably related to network), traffic can stop without triggering a connection error.  To solve this problem, I thought that I may use heart beat so I added the following to my js:

```
function Connect() {
    console.log('Connecting...');
    // Connect
    var ws = new SockJS(mq_url);
    client = Stomp.over(ws);
    client.heartbeat.outgoing = 5000;   // if 5000 means client will send heart beat every 5000ms
    client.heartbeat.incoming = 5000;   // if 0 means client does not want to receive heartbeats from server
    client.debug = function (str) {
        $("#debug").append(timeStamp() + str + "<br>");  
        varmessage = str;
    };
    client.connect(
    mq_username, mq_password, on_connect, on_connect_error, mq_vhost);
}
```

However, the server doesn't send heart beat so the following error is thrown:

```
-> PING
-> PING
did not receive server activity for the last 10017ms
Whoops!  Lost connection to undefined
```

I tried adding heartbeat param to rabbitmq.config, but that didn't appear to work.  The doc doesn't mention whether the heartbeat parameter is for client or server heartbeat.

```
[
       {rabbit, [
                {cluster_nodes, {['rabbit@server'], disc}},
                 {cluster_partition_handling, autoheal},
         {heartbeat, 1}
        ]},
```

Answer (score 2):

The heartbeat parameter is implemented on the client. RabbitMQ will respond to the heartbeat sent out by the client. The server can request clients to send heartbeats at a certain interval, but the client does not have to follow. [AMQP Reference](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#connection.tune); [RabbitMQ reference](http://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html)